# How to create a scheme component in xml and to use it as a response example

Tags: json, xml, api, swagger, openapi

I want to create a xml component that I will use it as a response example in a documentation.

Here is my non working code:

This is the request

```
"/descarcare1": {
  "get": {
    "tags": [
      ""
    ],
    "summary": "Descarcare mesajaaaaa",
    "description": "Intoarce un PDF cu mesajul din SPV corespunzător ID-ului trimis ca parametru\n",
    "operationId": "descarcaMesaj2",

    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "Succes sau eroare",
        "content": {
          "application/xml": {
             "schema": {
                "oneOf": [

                {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ComponentaXML"
                }
                        ]
                    }

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the component:

```
"ComponentaXML": {

                "type":"object",
                "properties": {
                "eroare": {
                "type":"string",
                "example": "Id descarcare introdus= 35045838a nu este un numar intreg"
                },
                "titlu":{
                "type":"string",
                "example":"Descarcare mesaj"
                }}}
```

The other components are JSON type and they are rendering as response example and working fine. Please help

Answer (score 0):

In the response definition, replace

```
          "application/xml": {
            "schema": {
              "oneOf": [
                {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ComponentaXML"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
```

with

```
          "application/xml": {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ComponentaXML"
            }
          }
```